# Data Structure in C++. insertion in the beginning of the node in linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am learning data structures in C++. This is a simple program for insertion 
using links and nodes. The insertion takes place at the beginning of the node.
I do not understand some parts of the code.

In the function `display()` the pointer `np` points to the inserted info and then takes the value of the previous info using the next node. The next pointer is pointing to the previous info using the `insert_beginning()` function.
Displaying is done using the `while` loop. How does the next pointer change its value during each loop?

PS: The program runs fine.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<process.h>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

 struct node
 {
     int info;
     node *next;
 }*start,*newptr,*save,*ptr;

 node *create_new_node(int);
 void insert_beg(node*);
 void display(node*);

 /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 The pointer 'start' points to the beginning of the list.

 Function 'create_new_node()' takes one integer argument , allocates memory to create new node and returns
 the pointer to the new node.(return type: node*)

 Function 'insert_beg()' takes node* type pointer as an argument and inserts this node in the beginning of the list.

 Function display takes node* type pointer as an argument and displays the list from this pointer till the end of the list

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

 int main()
 {
     start=NULL;
     int inf;
     char ch='y';
     while(ch=='y'||ch=='Y')
     {
         system("cls");

         cout<<"enter information for the new node ";
         cin>>inf;
         cout<<"\ncreating new node. Press enter to continue ";
         system("pause");

         newptr = create_new_node(inf);

         if(newptr!=NULL)
         {
             cout<<"\nnew node created successfully. Press enter to 
continue. ";
             system("pause");

         }

         else
         {

             cout<<"\nCannot create new node. ABORTING!! ";
             exit(1);

         }

         cout<<"\nnow inserting this node in the beginning of the list. 
Press enter to continue ";
         system("pause");
         insert_beg(newptr);
         cout<<"\nNow the list is \n";
         display(start);
         cout<<"\nPress 'Y' to enter more nodes, 'N' to exit\n";
         cin>>ch;

     }

     return 0;
 }

 node *create_new_node(int n)
 {
     ptr=new node;
     ptr->info=n;
     ptr->next=NULL;

 }

 void insert_beg(node *np)
 {

        if(start==NULL)
        start=np;
      else
     {
         save=start;
         start=np;
         np->next=save;
     }

 }

 void display(node *np)
 {

     while(np!=NULL)
     {
         cout<<np->info<<" ->";
         np=np->next;

     }
     cout<<"!!!\n";
 }
```

Comment: How is the function display related to inserting nodes?!

Comment: every node in link list contains the address of the next node, so `np->next` points to the next node which address is assigned to `np` again `np = np->next`, that's how the `np` moves to next node.

Answer (score 0):

To cut the long story short - per my understanding, your basic question is:-

> display is done using the while loop. how does the next pointer change
>   its value during each loop??

This happens precisely in this line:-

`np=np->next;`

You are basically advancing the pointer to the `node` structure to another `node` structure whose address is in `next` member of the first node structure. This is text book stuff and any basic algo book should cover this thoroughly

HTH!

Comment: next holds the address of the previous node. np takes the value from that address. then how does next point to another node.

Comment: next holds the address of the next node not the previous one

Comment: This happens precisely in this line:- `np=np->next`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear. Especially because you state that:

> PS:the program runs fine.

which it for sure does **not**. There is a bug that simply means this program will not work.

The problem is that `create_new_node` is not returning the pointer value

```
 node *create_new_node(int n)
 {
     ptr=new node;
     ptr->info=n;
     ptr->next=NULL;
     return ptr;      // This line is missing
 }
```

Besides that it is a really bad idea to use global pointer variables!

Here

```
 struct node
 {
     int info;
     node *next;
 }*start,*newptr,*save,*ptr;
```

you define the `struct node` but you also define 4 variables, i.e. 4 pointers to node. These variables will be global, i.e. available in all your code. Something that you should **never** do.

Instead make local variables as needed - for instance:

```
 node *create_new_node(int n)
 {
     node *ptr;   // Local variable instead of global
     ptr=new node;
     ptr->info=n;
     ptr->next=NULL;
     return ptr;
 }
```

Then for the `insert_beg` change it so that it returns a new start pointer - like:

```
 node* insert_beg(node* start, node *np)
 {
     np->next=start;
     return np;
 }
```

and use it in `main` like:

```
node* start = NULL;
...
...
start = insert_beg(start, newptr);
```

BTW - In modern C++ you would never use raw pointers and you would never write your own list. Use smart pointers instead of raw pointer. Use the standard containers instead of writing your own.

Comment: actually the program runs without the suggested edit. I did think of returning the pointer from create_new_node() but the compilation and output is fine. btw...wud u elaborate about smart pointers?

Comment: @SohitGore 1) The program just can't run correct without the `return ptr` 2) Smart pointers... well, the problem with raw pointers is that many programmers couldn't handle them. They forgot to free/delete the memory which caused lots of problems (aka memory leaks). So a smart pointer is a way to delegate that responsibility to a special class, i.e. a unique pointer or a shared pointer - the smart pointer will handle release of memory automatically - like a sort of garbage collection. If you want to do modern C++ you should read about them.

Comment: @SohitGore - BTW: Remember to always turn warnings into error (i.e. compiler option). Your compiler is screaming at you for not having a return in that function :-)